# Ordinary differential equation and first integral - help!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Ok, so I started learning ODE, and got my first H.W., but I have no idea even how to begin!

The question is to find the "first integral" of the following ODE:

$3t·(\cos t)u^2u'+(\cos t -t\sin t)u^3=0$

Later, I need to find "the first integral" of the equation that I get from comparing the previous "first integral" to a const.
And if possible, to solve this ODE.

Of course, this is only the first ODE for this question, but I have no idea how to start solving it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first strategy in such situations, try if you can identify functions $f$ and $g$ such that your ODE reads as
$$
f(t)g'(u)u'+f'(t)g(u)=0
$$
since then you can employ the product rule to find that your equation is the same as 
$$
(f(t)g(u))'=0
$$
which has an easy first integral.

Comment: So the first integral is $t*cost*u^3$?

Comment: @WakaWaka123: Yes. It is not always that simple, then the best that can happen is that separation of variables works, as in the answer of E.H.E. See also "exact differential equation", where one treats essentially the same class of questions.

Comment: and how can I solve the ODE?

Comment: $u(t)=u(t_0)\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{t_0\cos t_0}{t\cos t}}$ is the obvious solution. It is of course only valid between two zeros of $t\cos t$.

Answer (score 1):

by using the separable method

$$\frac{du}{u}=\frac{t\sin t-\cos t}{3t\cos t}dt$$
$$\frac{du}{u}=(\frac{1}{3}\tan t-\frac{1}{3t})dt$$